# Compare multiple worksheets from different excel files

Tags: excel, vba

I need one more step to complete  this  task  in vba .. So, guys I need some assistance here  , any help will be welcomed.

I need to compare multiple worksheets between two excel files.
First [for  cycles ] is to check if that sheet name is in both  excel files and if so then compared/ find differences in the cell , else if that sheet is not exist in both  excel files then  color the  sheet with yellow colour.

But I'm stuck here.. I'm constantly  getting an error: 'Invalid Next control variable reference'. Maybe my method here to compare sheet name is not probably good defined.
Here is  my  code ,  I hope this makes sense..

```
Option Explicit
Sub Compare_Two_Excel_Sheets()
    'Define Fields
    Dim Flag As Double
  
    Dim iR As Double, iC As Double, oRw As Double, fone As Double, ftwo As Double
    Dim iRow_M As Double, iCol_M As Double, ifiles_one As Double, ifiles_two As Double
    
    Dim s1 As Workbook, s2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim s3 As Workbook
    Flag = 0
    
    'Path
    Set s1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="File1_Path.xlsx")
    Set s2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="File2_Path.xlsx")
   
   'Sheet1_compare_sheetName
   
    Set ws1 = s1.Sheet(1)
    Set ws2 = s2.Sheet(1)
    
    ifiles_one = ws1.Name
    ifiles_two = ws2.Name
    
    For fone = 1 To ifiles_one
    For ftwo = 1 To ifiles_two
    
    ws1.Names(fone, ftwo).Interior.Color = xlNone
    ws2.Names(fone, ftwo).Interior.Color = xlNone
    
 If ws1.Names(fone, ftwo) = ws2.Names(fone, ftwo) Then
          
    
    'Sheet1
    'count columns and rows
    iRow_M = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    iCol_M = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    
    For iR = 1 To iRow_M
    For iC = 1 To iCol_M
        ws1.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = xlNone
        ws2.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = xlNone
        
        If ws1.Cells(iR, iC) <> ws2.Cells(iR, iC) Then
           ws1.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = vbYellow
           ws2.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = vbYellow
           
           oRw = oRw + 1
         
          Flag = Flag + 1
         
        End If
        
    Next iC
    Next iR
    
    If Flag > 0 Then
        VBA.Interaction.MsgBox "Differences exist, please check the yellow fields in Sheet1!"
        Else: VBA.Interaction.MsgBox "No differences found!"
    
  End If

End If
Next fone
Next ftwo

Else
ws1.Names(fone, ftwo).Interior.Color = vbYellow
           ws2.Names(fone, ftwo).Interior.Color = vbYellow
 


End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense `ifiles_one As Double` then `ifiles_one = ws1.Name` unless the sheet names are numbers. I'm guessing you want `ifiles_one = s1.sheets.count` the number of sheets in the workbook Inside loop `Set ws1 = s1.Sheets(fone)` and  `Set ws2 = s2.Sheets(ftwo)`. then `If ws1.Name = ws2.Name Then`

Comment: @CDP1802
hm  ,  I think your suggestion makes sense.. but.. i still have this annoying compile error:  :"Invalid Next control variable reference '

Comment: these are in the wrong order `Next fone Next ftwo`. You can use `Next Next` without the variable name

Comment: when i try that way, I've got new  compile error: Expected: variable .. 
 hm what do you think , where  I should try to put these variables?  Now there are after the last End If..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Compare_Two_Excel_Sheets()
    'Define Fields
    Dim Flag As Long, t0 As Single
    Dim iR As Long, iC As Long, oRw As Long
    Dim iRow_M As Long, iCol_M As Long
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
   
    t0 = Timer 'start time
    Flag = 0
    
    'Path
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="File1_Path.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="File2_Path.xlsx")
    
    ' compile list of wb2 sheet names
    Dim dict As Object, sName As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each ws2 In wb2.Sheets
        dict.Add ws2.Name, 0
        ws2.Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    Next
   
    ' compare with wb1 sheet names
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws1 In wb1.Sheets

        sName = ws1.Name
        iRow_M = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        iCol_M = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        ws1.Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
        
        If dict.exists(sName) Then
            dict(sName) = 1 ' mark as match
            Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets(sName)
            
            If ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count > iRow_M Then
                iRow_M = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            End If
            
            If ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count > iCol_M Then
                iCol_M = ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count
            End If
            
           'compare sheets ws1 ws2
            For iR = 1 To iRow_M
                For iC = 1 To iCol_M
           
                    If ws1.Cells(iR, iC) <> ws2.Cells(iR, iC) Then
                       ws1.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                       ws2.Cells(iR, iC).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                       
                       oRw = oRw + 1
                       Flag = Flag + 1
                       
                    End If
                Next iC
            Next
        Else
            ws1.Cells.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Flag = Flag + 1
        End If
    Next
    
    ' sheets in wb2 not matched
    For Each ws2 In wb2.Sheets
        sName = ws2.Name
        If dict(sName) = 0 Then
            ws2.Cells.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            Flag = Flag + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim msg As String
    If Flag > 0 Then
        msg = "Differences exist, please check the yellow fields in Sheet1!"
    Else:
        msg = "No differences found!"
    End If
    MsgBox msg, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0") & " secs"
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You say: *I'm constantly getting an error: 'Invalid Next control variable reference'.*

Your `For ... Next` loops `fone` and `ftwo` are incorrectly written as

```
    For fone = 1 To ifiles_one
    For ftwo = 1 To ifiles_two

    Next fone
    Next ftwo
```

The `Next` of the inner loop (`ftwo`) must be before the `Next`of the outer loop (`fone`). Properly indented it is easy to get it right:

```
    For fone = 1 To ifiles_one
        For ftwo = 1 To ifiles_two
            ...
        Next ftwo
    Next fone
```

Comment: yes  you're right i missed that! thanks!
Now I must figure it out on my next compile error msg: Subscript out of range. and when I debugging gives' me this line : Set ws1 = s1.Sheets(fone)

Comment: What is the value of `fone` when you get the error?

Comment: I don't see any line with `Set ws1 = s1.Sheets(fone)` in the code you have posted. OTOH, continuous searching for new errors is not how SO works. You posted a question, I answered it. If my post answered your question, then please mark it as correct by clicking the tick mark beside my answer green. For an eventual new problem, post a new question. But before that please format your code with proper indentation, it might visualize and clarify the new problem for you.

Comment: 'I answered it. If my post answered your question, then please mark it as correct by clicking the tick mark beside my answer green' I appoligize I didn't notice that tick.

Comment: That's OK, we all go through a 'learning process' ;)

Comment: Leo, I just noticed when I refreshed my display that you have also received an answer from @CDP1802. Their answer answers much more than you originally asked (which I answered). You may want to, and it is your right, to change the tick mark from my answer to theirs. To change it, simply click their tick mark green, which will reset mine.